# Browsing the phone registered accounts

Tags: android

I want that instead of entering manually an email on my app, that I will open the Registered Emails (device account) on the app.
I saw it once on another app.
How  can this be achieved?

thanks!

Comment: Low quality question.  You want what?  What other app?  You don't think we might find it useful to know which app you've seen the desired functionality on, like we're all psychic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, May be I understood the question incorrectly, You need

```
    Account[] accounts = AccountManager.get(this).getAccounts();  
    for (Account account : accounts) {   
    // TODO: Check possibleEmail against an email regex or treat 
  //account.name as an email address only for certain account.type values.  
     String possibleEmail = account.name;
       ... 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Launch an intent:

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

String aEmailList[] = { "user@fakehost.com","user2@fakehost.com" };
String aEmailCCList[] = { "user3@fakehost.com","user4@fakehost.com"};
String aEmailBCCList[] = { "user5@fakehost.com" };

emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, aEmailList);
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_CC, aEmailCCList);
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_BCC, aEmailBCCList);

emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "My subject");

emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "My message body.");

startActivity(emailIntent);
```